# Xebium, fitnesse & Selenium Pause

Tags: fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

Im currently using Xebium, which is allows Selenium to be used with Fitnesse testing.
In Selenium i can set a pause for 3000 milliseconds. When i look at the source code for fitnesse it has the following line :

```
| do | pause | on | 3000 |
```

However when  i run this test in fitnesse it doesn't wait for 3 seconds liek i thought it would and goes on to the next line instead.

I need the pause for the screen to load a button properly.
I think fitnesse has a problem with seleniums use of pause or interrupts it another way.

Comment: Have you reported this to the Xebium project on gitub?  I don't know their code, but FitNesse generally does a good job honoring pauses in all of the fixtures I have written (including my company's Selenium based test driver).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

`ensure | do | pause | on | 3000 |`

I know it's been more than two years but I hope this will help people like me who have just started working on Xebium. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for future visitors: Have you tried waiting for the button to appear? Selenium documentation suggests doing this:

> Many Actions can be called with the “AndWait” suffix, e.g. “clickAndWait”. This suffix tells Selenium that the action will cause the browser to make a call to the server, and that Selenium should wait for a new page to load.

Found at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#selenium-commands-selenese

Comment: a little late yeh lol, however i think i did try this at some point but i remember it was temperamental, meaning if it just waited for the button then it would be too quick for something else on the page, and it you wait for the page thats when something didnt work properly